# How to format Azure WAD Log messages Pushed using Sink?

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics, wadslogtable

We have a bunch of Azure Service Fabric Services. We are currently using WAD for pushing all the ETW logs to Event hub. The event read from the Azure EH looks like below -

{
               "records": [{
                              "time": "2016-12-01T03:54:36.3117117Z",
                              "category": "*-*",
                              "level": "Informational",
                              "properties": {
                                             "DeploymentId": "2c07d034-de51-4c7b-a733-7147124512ef",
                                             "Role": "IaaS",
                                             "RoleInstance": "*-*",
                                             "Level": 0,
                                             "ProviderGuid": "a26b2183-a5f0-5eeb-a02d-ea55c138fcb9",
                                             "ProviderName": "*-*",
                                             "EventId": 1,
                                             "Pid": 5836,
                                             "Tid": 2936,
                                             "OpcodeName": "",
                                             "KeywordName": "Session3;Session2;Session1;Session0",
                                             "TaskName": "*-*",
                                             "ChannelName": "",
                                             "EventMessage": "Verbose",
                                             "ActivityId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                                             "RelatedActivityId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                              }
                                             "**Message**": "traceId=\"c365ffeb-0c10-4b8b-bc12-12a79aab19bd\" correlationId=\"\" userId=\"System\"auditTypeId=\"1\" auditEvent=\"*-*\" auditSource=\"*-*" cloudDeploymentId=\"\" auditLevel=\"Verbose\" auditMessage=\"*-*" tags=\"\" dataCenter=\"**\""
               }]
}

Is their a way i can format the message in Azure WAD?. Basically , I want to format the Message to have a separator instead of just the space in the middle of key value pairs.

Comment: "**format the message in Azure WAD**", if I understand correctly, you mean format the later part starting from "**Message: traceid ...**", right? If so, you can control the message format directly in your code. Find the **ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage** method for reliable service, or **ActorEventSource.Current.ActorMessage** method if it's a reliable actor, then you can format the message as you like.

Comment: Check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-how-to-monitor-and-diagnose-services-locally#add-your-own-custom-traces-to-the-application-code) for details.